# How can this kebab have so much protein and so little fat?

Tags: kebab

All my life I've been told that kebab (the meat, not the dish) is high-fat.

However, I was in the market the other day, and I found the following pack of frozen kebab. Below is a picture from that market's website. You can see that it's got 166kcal per 100 grams, only 6 grams of fat, and a whopping 25 grams of protein.

That sounds ... super high protein, and relatively low fat, to me. Not as much so as chicken breasts, but it's close.

What's going on here? Is this fraud, are they lying? Or can kebab really be like this?

Note that I've found similar packs of frozen kebab in other stores, and never did they have 25 grams of protein per 100g, and the fat content was always higher than the protein content.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Nobody is lying, different Doner meats have different fat contents, that's true of the ones in the stores as well as the ones in restaurants. Doner is a processed meat product made of ground meat and fat mixed with spices and usually preservatives. Sometimes fillers and binders are added as well. There's no rule saying a doner must have a specific amount of fat, it's all up to the manufacturer and the product they are trying to produce.

A "lite" doner may sound like a contradiction in terms but someone more health conscious may pick it because it has less fat and calories.

Comment: As a note, Yogurt also contains a lot of protein.